# What does the phrase 'waking thoughts' mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, word-in-context

Passage:

> Suddenly he was standing on short springy turf, on a summer evening when the
>   slanting rays of the sun gilded the ground. The landscape that he was looking at
>   recurred so often in his dreams that he was never fully certain whether or not he had seen it in the real world. In his **waking thoughts** he called it the Golden Country

*(George Orwell 1984)*

Question:

> What does the phrase 'waking thoughts' mean?

[Link to the book (page #21)](http://www.planetebook.com/ebooks/1984.pdf)

Comment: You were a bit quick to accept that answer... https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer

Comment: This question is getting into a bit of a mess. *Please* don't ask multiple questions in a single post!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I accidently saved editing of a wrong question, so it wasn't in purpose

Comment: I'll just point out that I can't find a single instance of ***Take your time by me*** in the whole of Google Books that *isn't* a direct quote from *1984*. But there are several hundred instances of [*Take your time **from** me*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Take+your+time+from+me%22), which would be my choice of preposition. The meaning is the same though - *Look/listen to me to establish the rhythm / beat / pace*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you can find this expression [link page #40](http://www.planetebook.com/ebooks/1984.pdf)

Comment: I know - I'm just pointing out that Orwell's preposition usage there is *not* what people would usually say.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/waking) provides different definitions of **waking** as a noun and as an adjective. The noun meaning relates to the **moment of waking**. In this context, the word is used as an adjective, and so the adjectival  definition is relevant: **used to refer to a period of time or an experience during which you are awake**.

According to [this definition](http://www.yourdictionary.com/waking), **waking** means **marked by full consciousness, awareness, and alertness**. To quote further from the link:

> This adjective most often occurs in phrases such as “every waking moment", “every waking hour", “every waking breath", and so on, the sense being roughly “at all times". Such phrases are often used together with possessives, such as in “her every waking moment" or “my every waking thought".

So, **waking thoughts** refers to anything that you think about when you are not asleep.

The expression can be used to describe what you are **always** thinking about: this might be relevant in this context, but it is more likely to simply be a contrast with the reference earlier in the paragraph to **in his dreams**.