# What does the phrase 'take your time by me' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Passage:

> Arms bending and stretching!' she rapped out. '**Take your time by me**. One, two,
>   three, four! One, two, three, four! Come on, comrades, put a bit of life into it!

*(George Orwell 1984)*

Question:

> What does the phrase 'take your time by me' mean?

[Link to the book (page #40)](http://www.planetebook.com/ebooks/1984.pdf)

Comment: Ah, I see you corrected the author's name. It means: use my timing for the exercise.

Comment: Orwell was into innuendos (what with **double-speak**), so who knows what else it might mean. Take your time usually has a different meaning and the combination with "by me" is very good reason to stop and consider. There are [no ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+your+time+by+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) not even of *1984*!?

Comment: @Hector von: I've never come across the idea that Orwell was into innuendos. If anything, I'd say he had quite the opposite position, in that it seems to me his [*Politics and the English Language*](http://www.orwell.ru/library/essays/politics/english/e_polit/), for example, primarily argues in favour of "simple, direct, unambiguous" phrasing. Also see [this comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124984/what-does-the-phrase-waking-thoughts-mean#comment252381_124984) from when the current question was included in a completely different one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that shows at least he was concerned with ambiguity. He doesn't have to equip a character with his own opinions, quite the opposite for literary effect. The whole scene is about the invasion of precious **private* **time*** at the **primary *time*** of the day (from pri~ and pre~). I'm just saying the meaning isn't narrow. I guess he meant **to focus on the exercise** including but not limited to the rhythm and the tempo. There are different examples, i.e. "*to take time by the forelock" (to look ahead).

Comment: @Hector: To *take time by the forelock* is hardly "normal English" -
 it was already recorded as a "set phrase" in 1736 [*Dictionarium Britannicum Or a More Compleat Universal Etymological English*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22vigorous+to+take+Time+by+the+Forelock%22) I suspect Orwell rarely encountered real-world contexts for the cited usage and simply made a (trivial) non-standard choice "by accident", rather than deliberately trying to impart some nuance. His *Put some life into it!* clearly implies the speaker is at least *trying* to sound "natural".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, on the other hand, if he did encounter it though, he might have chosen it as an example of ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the repeated counting from one to four afterwards, this is an instruction to follow the [tempo](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tempo), or [rhythm](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rhythm), set by the speaker.

Comment: Yes. In AmE we'd say "take your time **from** me".

Comment: @StoneyB, Agreed, I  thought about saying the same for BrE, but I couldn't find any references to back it up.